# How to post FileReader object using $.ajax and asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, filereader

I want add temporary images first and then on submit i want to add all those images to server.

Here is my class

```
public class UserModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public List<AcademicDetailModel> AcademicDetails { get; set; } 
}

public class AcademicDetailModel 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public int CollegeId { get; set; }
     public HttpPostedFileBase DegreeFile { get; set; }
     public String DegreeFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
    var arrAcademicDetail = new Array();
    function AcademicDetailModel() {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.UserId = 0;
        this.CollegeId = 0;           
        this.DegreeFile=new FileReader();
    }
</script>
```

here is my click event that adds temp image to the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAcademic').click(function () {

             var _AcademicDetailModel = new AcademicDetailModel();
             _AcademicDetailModel.Id=(arrAcademicDetail.length)+1;
             _AcademicDetailModel.CollegeId = $('#CollegeId').val();                   

             if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                 var file = document.getElementById("DegreeFilePath").files[0];
                 _AcademicDetailModel.DegreeFile=file;
                }


             arrAcademicDetail.push(_AcademicDetailModel);


        })
 })
```

here is the final submit event that submits data to the server.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AcademicDetail", "Home")',
            data: { "Model": {
                "Id":UserId,
                "AcademicDetails": arrAcademicDetail
            }},
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function () {
                DDU.blockUI({ message: "Please wait.." });
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                //Other Process
            },
            complete: function () {
                DDU.unblockUI();

            },
            error: function () {
                DDU.unblockUI();
                bootbox.alert("Oops ! you caught an error.<br/><br/><b>Possible Reason</b> <br/>- Invalid data");      
            }
        });
```

here is my action

```
public ActionResult AcademicDetail(UserModel Model)
{
   try
   {
   }
   catch()
   {
   }
}
```

but in this action i get Model.AcademicDetails null.

Answer (score 0):

You should decorate your api object with FormData to have ability to post form data with images/files to the server with ajax.

Simple example:

```
    var saveUserRequest = function (userModel, callback) {
        var userModel = new FormData();
        model.append('image', userModel.image);  // this has the file for sure (document.getElementById("DegreeFilePath").files[0])

        model.append('userId', userModel.Id);
        model.append('userName', userModel.Name);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/UserApi/SaveUser',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: model,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            complete: function (data) {
                callback && callback(data);
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
    };
```

Note: Your html form should have enctype="multipart/form-data"

Than in the controller, you can access passed data in such way:

```
HttpPostedFile imageFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["image"];
```

and, for example, userId/userName:

```
var userId = Int32.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["userId"]);
var userName = Int32.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["userName"])
```